# Gradient to <td> cell acording to percentage??Percentage is calculated by some array values

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, visualization, css

[image: This is what i want to achieve]
image indicates 70% when x=0.7

Observe this fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/jayeshjain24/ddfsb/1/

**According to the values inside the boxes,gradient should appear.The following details has some info about what should be done:::**

```
Formula------>    (x/1)*100=Percentage.(this determines the % of gradient!!!)
x will vary from 0 to 0.999
```

where **x=the values that you see in boxes(viz.0.06,0.09,0.9 etc)**.These value come from *var data* which is *array* having *first element=some random id(ignore this)* and *second element as multidimensional or simple array()!!!All the values that you see in boxes are second parameter of the array*

What I want is to calcutate the percentage based on that value using above formula and then display it in percentage like i did with the above image.

```
COLOR-CODE for above image--->background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(30,87,153,1)), color-stop(67%,rgba(28,31,178,1)), color-stop(80%,rgba(144,192,229,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
```

Generated From--> http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

-----------------------------------------------------------Simplification-------------------------------------------------

```
Lets say if value==0.5
```

if the cell is from first row-->then

1. assume blue as a parent color(so the gradient will be blue and light
   blue,you can have any parent color you wish,but gradient should be
   relative)
2. convert 0.5 in percentage using above formula--->gives you 50%...so
   50 percent dark blue followed by 50% light blue.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean. Do you want to fill the cells with a single background color that is determined by the value, or do you want a gradient as background?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff --->yes,Gradient as background to individual cells...coz every cell has some different value!!!But array values determine how my horizontal gradient will look i.e giving it a meter like appearance.Am i clear??

Comment: How is that gradient determined? What are the start and end colors and what does the number for a cell specify?

Comment: Basically i am making a tabular chart,there is some json with more than 10k values which shows me Google Analytics hit report,for simplicity purpose i have reduced those values!!!
Fisrt column has blue color and above gradient----second column has orange and any orangish gradient will do,same for red and red and green.

Comment: Note-->i have some 6 to 7 column and every column should have a parent color(example-->red,orange,green,blue).Gradients will be given to every cells according to their value.the problem i am facing is how do i provide conditions and iterate over each cell.
Am i clear?

Comment: start and end colors--->whatever you wish!!!!it will be better if you go with my colours!!!

Comment: @LarsKotthoff:is this possible to do?

Comment: The answer is almost certainly yes, but I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. Say the value for a cell is 0.5, what exactly do you want the background to be?

Comment: if the cell is from first row-->then
1)blue as a parent color(so the gradient will be blue and light blue,you can have any parent color you wish,but gradient should be relative)
2)convert 0.5 in percentage using above formula--->gives you 50%...so 50 percent dark blue followed by 50% light blue..Am i clear now??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the same `webkit-gradient` string dynamically. I've updated your jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ddfsb/2/) with what I think you mean. The relevant code is below.

```
.style('background', function(d) {
  if(d.value) {
    var col = d3.rgb(colors(d.value[0]));
    return "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%," +
            col.darker(3) + "), color-stop(" + (d.value[2] * 100) + "%," +
            col + "), color-stop(100%," + col.brighter(3) + "))";
  } else {
    return "white";
  }
})
```

The methods `.darker()` and `.brighter()` are provided by D3 and do what they say -- you may want to replace them with custom start/end colours.

Comment: Bingooooo!!!!finally...
But can the gradient be a little sharper so that they can signify a more accurate values and ----this is what my delimma was,how are youable to generate orangish gradient for orange color,bluish gradient for blue color....and same for yellow and green

Comment: You can make it sharper by moving the end points closer -- http://jsfiddle.net/ddfsb/4/